# ipython notebook startup file

Tags: pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have the following startup in the ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup location:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.environ["PYTHONPATH"])
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 999)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 999)
pd.set_option("precision", 5)
```

Now for some reason the PYTHONPATH is working but the pandas display options are not. Anything you recommend I try to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the following in `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` file. It automatically executes when you start notebook in command line `ipython notebook`. Some options I find useful:

```
# Configuration file for ipython.

c = get_config()

c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
    'from __future__ import print_function, division',
    '%matplotlib inline',
    'import sys, os',
    'sys.path.append(os.environ[\'PYTHONPATH\'])',
    'os.chdir(\'path/to/your/working/dir\')',    
    'import pandas as pd',
    'import numpy as np',    
    'pd.options.display.notebook_repr_html = False',
    'pd.options.display.max_rows = 20',
    'pd.options.display.max_columns = 20',
    'pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False',
    'pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 28',
    'pd.options.display.precision = 5',
    'np.set_printoptions(precision=4, linewidth=90, threshold=25)',
    'import datetime as dt',
    'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt'
]
c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = u'path/to/your/notebook/dir'
c.IPythonWidget.font_size = 12
c.IPythonWidget.font_family = "Ubuntu Mono"
c.ZMQInteractiveShell.colors = "LightBG"
```